# How to group by column and ignore NULLS within rows

Tags: t-sql

Hi have a table like this:

```
langaugeCode   titleText    introText
en            WeeklyTitle   NULL
en            NULL          This text
de            HereItIs      NULL
de            NULL          ThereThere
```

Essentailly I want to group by language code but ignore the columns within a row that are NULL.

I would like to transform this table to:

```
langaugeCode   titleText    introText
en            WeeklyTitle   This text
de            HereItIs      ThereThere
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try aggregating by `languageCode` and taking the maximum value of each column:

```
SELECT
    languageCode,
    MAX(titleText) AS titleText,
    MAX(introText) AS introText
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    languageCode;
```

[image]

### Demo

This works because the `MAX()` aggregate function by default ignores `NULL` values.  So, assuming you only have a single non `NULL` value for each language code, it would be retained during the aggregation.

Comment: It does work indeed by we can't be sure that OP doesn't have possible multiple values for "de" or "en" for example.

Comment: If there could be more than one non `NULL` value, then the problem itself may not be meaningful, e.g. `titleText` has two non `NULL` values, `introText` has three non `NULL` values; how to render that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add where condition for not null check for the columns you don't want null value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd "merge" it by doing this:

Make a two tables (t1 and t2) and make a natural join on it.

```
SELECT
    t2.languageCode, t1.titleText, t2.introText
FROM (SELECT
        yt1.languageCode, yt1.titleText, yt1.introText
    FROM yourTable yt1
    GROUP BY
        languageCode) t1, yourTable t2
WHERE
    t1.languageCode = t2.languageCode
GROUP BY
    t2.languageCode, t1.titleText, t2.introText;
```

Try it ;)

Comment: Please stop using implicit joins. Explicit joins have been a part of ANSI-SQL for over 25 years now.

Comment: Doesn't mean that the query isn't correct in terms of semantic.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the semantic of the query, just noted about the join style. BTW, this query doesn't really make much sense to me, and SQL Server will throw an error on it anyway, since `titleText` and `introText` are in the `select` clause but not in the `group by` clause.

Comment: I get a syntax error when running it:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: @DanielRoberts there was a semicolon, I just edited the code.